# code running from alarm manager dying after 1 minute

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I have some code that should take (roughly) 5 minutes to run. This code should run periodically, so I'm calling it using the built in `AlarmManager`.

Like this:

```
public void setAlarm(Context context)
{
    AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager)context.GetSystemService(Context.AlarmService);
    Intent i = new Intent(context, typeof(keyboardservice.alarmreciever));

    PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.GetBroadcast(context, 0, i, PendingIntentFlags.CancelCurrent);
    am.SetRepeating(AlarmType.ElapsedRealtimeWakeup, 0, 1000 * 60 * 30, pi); // Millisec * Second * Minute
}
```

As you can see the code should run every 30 minutes.

`AlarmService` looks something like this :

```
[BroadcastReceiver(Enabled = true)]
public class alarmreciever : BroadcastReceiver
{
    public override void OnReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        Task.Delay(1000 * 300).Wait();
    }
}
```

I've simplified the code above, but the result is the same the code dies after 1 minute (exactly), like there's some limit.

It doesn't matter if the screen is on or off.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved with :

```
new Task(() =>
            {

                DoAction(context);
            }).Start();
```

Answer (score 3):

> AlarmService looks something like this

That is not a `Service`. That is a `BroadcastReceiver`.

> What am I missing?

First, your `BroadcastReceiver` is attempting to tie up the main application thread for five minutes. Even if that were possible, it would be a profoundly bad idea, as that means that your UI would be frozen during those five minutes. But, it is not possible, as a watchdog should terminate your work in the ANR timeout period (10-15 seconds for background work IIRC).

Second, in general, you cannot do anything in the background for more than a minute on Android 8.0+. There are exceptions, notably if you use `JobScheduler`, where you have ~10 minutes.

If you are *sure* that your work will be completed in less than 10 minutes, then if your `minSdkVersion` is 21 or higher, switch to `JobScheduler`. If your `minSdkVersion` is below 21, at least on those older devices, have your `BroadcastReceiver` start a `JobIntentService`, were you do your five minutes of work in `onHandleWork()`.

Note that I do not know what of this has been Xamarin-ified, as I do not use Xamarin.